# Extracting web-page elements from item url using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to extract web-page data using `scrapy` and it's all going well until I need to collect multiple elements from the items url.

The website I'm extracting is eBay, and I'll send a response to the webpage and collect information on the items url, and price. Here's the specific code that I used:

```
def parse(self, response, page_cntr):
        if page_cntr > 5000:
            return
    all_cards = response.xpath('//div[@class="s-item__wrapper clearfix"]')
    for card in all_cards:
        loader = ItemLoader(EbayItem(), selector=card)
        loader.add_xpath('name', './/h3/text()')
        loader.add_xpath('price', './/span[@class="s-item__price"]//text()')
        loader.add_xpath('product_url', './/a[@class="s-item__link"]//@href')
```

And then I'll send the product urls to yield as a scrapy request to get the products url.  I'll iterate over the next few pages on the webpage (which is what the `page_cnt` is for) with my next code, but then when I create a function to extract details within the product url I then get issues.

It will work if I set my code up like this to get additional data along with that grabbed in the code-snippet above:

```
def parse_product_details(self, response, loader):
    location = response.xpath("//span[@itemprop='availableAtOrFrom']/text()").get()
    loader.add_value('location', location)
    yield loader.load_item()
```

However, if I wanted more information from the product page I would approach it like this:

```
def parse_product_details(self, response, loader):
        #location = response.xpath("//span[@itemprop='availableAtOrFrom']/text()").get()
        
        data_cards = response.xpath('//div[@class="tab-content-m"]').get()
        for details in data_cards:
            loader = ItemLoader(EbayItem(), selector=details)
            loader.add_xpath('condition','.//div[@class="ux-layout-section__row"][3]/div[@class="ux-labels-values__values"][2]/div[@class="ux-labels-values__values-content"]/div/span//text()')
            loader.add_xpath('character','.//div[@class="ux-layout-section__row"][1]/div[@class="ux-labels-values__values"][2]/div[@class="ux-labels-values__values-content"]/div/span//text()')
            loader.add_xpath('rarity','.//div[@class="ux-layout-section__row"][8]/div[@class="ux-labels-values__values"][2]/div[@class="ux-labels-values__values-content"]/div/span//text()')
            loader.add_xpath('graded','.//div[@class="ux-layout-section__row"][4]/div[@class="ux-labels-values__values"][2]/div[@class="ux-labels-values__values-content"]/div/span//text()')
            loader.add_xpath('set','.//div[@class="ux-layout-section__row"][1]/div[@class="ux-labels-values__values"][1]/div[@class="ux-labels-values__values-content"]/div/span//text()')
        yield loader.load_item()
```

But I get no data this way.
How can I grab additional details within the product page like it would do when I use the first two code snippets?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: better create minimal working code with real url so we could simply copy it and see problem.

Comment: maybe in `parse_product_details` you should use original `loader` instead of creating new one `loader = ItemLoader(EbayItem(), selector=details)` which doesn't know value from original `loader`. Maybe you should duplicate original `loader` in for-loop. And you should `yield` inside `for`-loop. If you use `yield` after `for`-loop then you send only one item.